# String.split function is not working properly with some text

Tags: javascript, string

I have string parser in node.js. Input string comes from telegram channel.
Now I have serious problem with `String.split` function.
It works with some types of text but it doesn't work with some other texts.
When I receive not processed string in telegram, I just copy and send it in the channel again.
In this case, parser processes it well.
Is there any advise for this issue?

```
        let teams = [];
        teamSeps =[" vs ", " v ", " - ", " x " ,"-", " -"];
        for(let i = 0; i< teamSeps.length; i++){
            teams = newTip.Match.toLowerCase().split(teamSeps[i]);
            if(teams.length === 2) break;
        }
        newTip.Home = teams[0].trim();
        newTip.Away = teams[1].trim();
        return;
```

Comment: well show us examples of what it works with and what it does not....

Comment: Why did you tag this as C#?

Comment: @mason If I had to guess, it was possibly to point out that they assumed JavaScript `split()` method had an overload similar to the C# overload that accepted an array of multiple char separators.

Comment: Hi, you are right. C# application reads the string from some website(C# scrapper).And the scrapper sends string into telegram channel  and Node JS parser reads and try to process the string. but it has such problem.
So I just copy the string in clipboard and try to paste on channel and parser reads the string and processes well.
So when I send string from c#, there might be any encoding problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding multiple options with optional spaces on either side of `-`, you can use a single regex with some [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
/\s*-\s*|\s+(?:vs|v|x)\s+/
```

- `\s*-\s*`: Allows optional space around `-`
- `\s+(?:vs|v|x)\s+`: Allows at least one space around `vs` or `v` or `x` (Otherwise, if there is a `x` or `v` in the string, it will split)

```js
function customSplit(str) {
  return str.split(/\s*-\s*|\s+(?:vs|v|x)\s+/);
}

console.log(customSplit("Man United vs Man City"))
console.log(customSplit("France - Croatia"))
console.log(customSplit("Belgium-England"))
console.log(customSplit("Liverpool x Spurs"))
```